# Spring AMQP - Is there a synchronous blocking send method that only waits for confirm?

Tags: spring, spring-amqp

I am using Spring AMQP v1.4.2 and trying to find a send method, possibly in [RabbitTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/api/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/core/RabbitTemplate.html), that blocks the thread until a **confirm** is received from the server to make sure we do not lose messages.

I have seen the `sendAndReceive()` method but it waits for a reply message  in an RPC style, while I just want to wait for a **confirm** on the channel. I know that I can use the `setConfirmCallback()` method but then it means it is not synchronous and I may end up on a different thread when the confirmation arrives and I will lose my thread-locals, i.e. lots of Spring goodies.

Is there anyway to achieve that in Spring AMQP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RabbitMQ gets huge performance benefits by using asynchronous publishing. As you say, you can configure publisher confirms to get an asynchronous confirmation that a message was delivered to a queue.

If you really want to block, you can use `setChannelTransacted(true)` on the `RabbitTemplate`; the `commit` will block until the message is secured in the queue(s).